# Similar font to Lithos Pro

Tags: font-recommendation, free

I'm searching a free alternative for [Adobe's Lithos Pro](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1711).

[image]

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any fonts that are nearly identical to that one, but here's one that is close:

[Stein Antik](http://www.dafont.com/steinantik.font)
[image: Stein Antik Font]

Others to consider:

[Carolus Roman](http://www.dafont.com/carolus-roman.font)
[image: Carolus Roman Font]

[Roman SD](http://www.dafont.com/roman-sd.font)
[image: Roman SD Font]